# How to hide label of Quasar select (q-select), when behaviour is set as 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

[image]

I wanted to remove the label header in case of 'dialog' behaviour for q-select.

Even if label is not passed its having an empty header. I can simply remove it using below css.

Using :global as the dialog is teleported and I am using scoped css.

```
:global(.q-select__dialog label){
  display: none
}
```

But issue is that I want to remove this for only one particular component. Not seeing an option to add a class to target this particular dialog.

Is there a better way to remove it ?

Example - https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#options-list-display-mode

Quasar - https://quasar.dev/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@popup-show` and `@popup-hide` event.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/dyejBeb

Comment: Hi @patel-pratik, I need to hide the entire highlighted section, not just the label text.